# Biological investigations or Biochemical investigations

Tags: biochemistry

I am working on phytochemicals and their antimicrobial and antioxidant activities.
Are these activities investigations called Biological investigations or Biochemical investigations?
What is the difference between them?

Comment: For what purpose do you want to use one of these labels?

Comment: As the name implies, biochemical relates to the chemical reactions in biological processes. If that is your focus, fine, if you are only interested in the events, inappropriate. But you don’t say, and if you check the meaning of these terms, you don’t need to post here.